# Array to string conversion error in FOR LOOP using CI

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Please help, why I received Message: Array to string conversion

Here's my code.

```
$remaining = 15000;
$amort = 3600;
$sales_mi = 3600;

for($remaining += $amort; $remaining > $amort; ($hi = ($remaining-=$amort) < $amort ? $remaining  : $amort) . 
    (($hi == $sales_mi) ? $data = array('amount'=>$hi)  : 'No') 
);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: please provide a bit more code, like what is in the array, and where is the body of the for loop?

Comment: Hi @swidmann please check update code

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of rewriting your loop to make it readable:

```
for($remaining += $amort; $remaining > $amort; $remaining -= $amort) {
    $hi = ($remaining) < $amort ? $remaining  : $amort;
    $hi .= ($hi == $sales_mi) ? $data = array('amount'=>$hi)  : 'No';
}
```

Now: In the second line of the body of the loop you are returning an array if the condition $hi == $sales_mi is true. And you are attaching that array as if it were a string (using the "." operator) to the $hi variable. That's why you have that error.

Comment: looks like the formula is incorrect, if my $sales_mi = 5742, and the customer paid 15000, it should be 5742, 5742, and 3516, I test your code above, and it show 5742, 5742 and 5742.

Comment: The formula may be incorrect, but now you know why you're getting that array to string conversion error. I leave the correction of the formula to you.

Comment: What the point of this post? Your question is: "Please help, why I received Message: Array to string conversion" I told you: You are using the array `array('amount'=>$hi)` as if it was a string. That's the answer. Question answered. Now you want that we rewrite your code so that it makes what you want to make (whatever it is). That's another thing.